# Creating a color gradient with LiveCharts - .net Maui

Tags: maui, livecharts

I see that there is a way to create a linear gradient with a bar or line graph on LiveChart.

https://lvcharts.com/docs/maui/2.0.0-beta.700/Overview.Paints

Is there a way to do this with a circular gauge?